# Mass creation of widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm using tkinter to create a calculator of sorts for one of my classes, and I've been making like 20 labels in a grid layout, using virtually the same line of code every time except the name and obviously the row number. I was just wondering if there was a standard way to quickly and effeciently make labels like this, or if someone has a quick way they use to break the tediousness?

For example, this is what my "code" basically looked like.

```
label0 = tk.Label(frame,
                  text="Label0")
label0.grid(row=0,
            column=0,
            sticky="E")

label1 = tk.Label(frame,
                  text="Label1")
label1.grid(row=1,
            column=0,
            sticky="E")

...

labeln = tk.Label(frame,
                  text="Labeln")
labeln.grid(row=n,
            column=0,
            sticky="E")
```

I tried creating a list or library of all the label names, then saying something like

```
labelnames = ["label0",
              "labebl1",
               ...,
              "labeln"]

for i in len(labelnames):
    labelx = tk.Label(frame,
                      text=labelnames[i])
    labelx.grid(row=i,
                column=0,
                sticky="E")
```

This works, but the point of this was to learn and I would like to know if there is a standard or "correct" way to do this. I tend to stray away from using classes because I still don't understand them (ironic I know), but I would like to learn if this were a better use for them.

A problem with this method that arises for me is I have an entry box corresponding to each label created using a similar loop, and I'm not sure how to get the input from the entry this way.

Comment: IMO there is nothing really wrong with the list and loop

Comment: BTW there's more beginner focused forums like reddit.com/r/learnpython if you feel bad about asking very simple questions here.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it correctly. We could make it a little neater using `enumerate`:

```
labels = []
for i, label in enumerate(labelnames):
    labelx = tk.Label(frame, text=label)
    labelx.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="E")
    labels.append(labelx)
```

I also added the resulting widgets to a list. That way I can access them later.

```
labels[2].config(text='new text') # update the text on the 3rd Label
```